# what is contact contract in winRT?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, contacts

for my winRT application i am using 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contact.aspx#properties

i want to add new contact to the application which allows me to pick there contact using contact picker.can i add new contact using Contact class in above link.if yes then how?thanks in advance.
i am using  Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts namespace.and ya i am working with c#.

Answer (score 0):

> [Manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.provider.aspx):
>
> To be launched as a Contact provider and let other apps access your app's contact data, register your app as a provider by including the following in the Extensions section of your app's manifest.
>   XML
>
> ```
> <Extension Category=”windows.contactPicker” />
> ```

Comment: hi, i did this.but my doubt is to add contact to other application like people hub.for example in my application i will take the contact details from user then add that contact to people hub